# RVM rails 3.2 and rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Im having trouble setting up a development environment. I need some tutorial on how to install rvm with rails 3.2 and rails 2.3.14 side by side. I tried installing rvm 1.8.7 then rails 2.3.14 and rvm 1.9.3 then rails 3.2. After finishing I can't seem to create a gemset and I tried to switch rvm 1.8.7 buy when I generate(ruby script/generate) it showed me that it was not recognized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally speaking, you would want to create your gemsets before installing the rails gems. This way the two versions are segregated. I would do something like the following:

```
rvm --create use 1.8.7@some-gemset-name
gem install rails -v 2.3.14
```

That should install and use those specific versions together. Then for the newer versions

```
rvm --create use 1.9.3@some-other-gemset-name
gem install rails
```

Then you would just need to change rubies and gemsets when you need to with `rvm use version@gemset-name`. Another approach is to have the ruby and gemset change with each rails project by creating a `.rvmrc` file in the root of your rails project. The contents of that file would be similar to the following:

```
rvm version@gemset-name
```

I would also recommend checking out the [RVM Docs](https://rvm.io/gemsets/) as this is just the tip of the iceberg when working with RVM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll be doing this and give you a feed back.